# (REACT) Componente funcional no se actualiza al cambiar el estado

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

Estoy haciendo un tic-tac-toe basico en react. Tengo cuatro componentes, tablero, cuadrilla, cruz y circulo. El problema es que cuando actualizo el estado del tablero no se llama al useEffect ni se ejecuta el render.

Tablero:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import "../Css/Board.css";
import "../Css/EndMessage.css"
import BoardBox from './BoardBox';

export default function Board (){
    const [boardBoxes, setBoardBoxes] = useState([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
    const [gameHasEnded, setGameHasEnded] = useState(false)
    const [winner, setWinner] = useState(0)

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(boardBoxes);
    },[boardBoxes]);

    let randomPlay = () => {
        function getRandomInt(min, max) {
            min = Math.ceil(min);
            max = Math.floor(max);
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        }
        
        let play = getRandomInt(0, 8);
        while(boardBoxes[play] !== 0){
            play = getRandomInt(0, 8);
        }

        markBox(play, 2)
    }


    let checkWinner = (callback) => {
        let winner = 0;
        let boxes = boardBoxes;

        if((boxes[0] === boxes[1] && boxes[1] === boxes[2]) ||
           (boxes[0] === boxes[3] && boxes[3] === boxes[6])){
               winner = boxes[0];
        }else if ((boxes[2] === boxes[5] && boxes[5] === boxes[8]) ||
                  (boxes[6] === boxes[7] && boxes[7] === boxes[8])) {
                    winner = boxes[8];
        }else if ((boxes[0] === boxes[4] &&  boxes[4] === boxes[8]) ||
                  (boxes[2] === boxes[4] && boxes[4] === boxes[6])) {
                    winner = boxes[4];
        }else if ((boxes[3] === boxes[4] &&  boxes[4] === boxes[5]) ||
                  (boxes[1] === boxes[4] && boxes[4] === boxes[7])) {
                    winner = boxes[4];
        }else if (boardBoxes.indexOf(0) === -1) {
                winner = 3; 
        }
        if (winner !== 0) {
            setGameHasEnded(true)
            setBoardBoxes([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
            setWinner(winner)
            setTimeout(() => {
                setGameHasEnded(false)
                setWinner(0)
            }, 1500);
        }else{
            callback();
        }
        
    }

    let markBox = (num, player) => {
        if (!gameHasEnded) {
            let boxes = boardBoxes;
            if (boxes[num] === 0) {
                boxes[num] = player;
                setBoardBoxes(boxes);
                checkWinner(() => {
                    if(!(boardBoxes.indexOf(0) === -1)){
                        if(player === 1){
                            randomPlay();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    return(
        !gameHasEnded
        ? <div className="BoardMainDiv">
            {(function() {
                let elements = []
                for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                    for(let j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                        elements.push(<BoardBox 
                        key={j+ 3*i} 
                        col={i} 
                        row={j} 
                        boxes={boardBoxes}
                        marked={boardBoxes[j+ 3*i] !== 0} 
                        markedPlayer={boardBoxes[j+ 3*i]}
                        markBox={markBox}
                        />);
                    } 
                } 

                return(elements)
            })()}
        </div>
        : winner !== 3
        ? <h1 className="EndMessage">Player: {winner} has won the game</h1>
        : <h1 className="EndMessage">It's a Tie</h1>
    );
}
```

Cuadrilla:

```
import React from 'react';
import "../Css/BoardBox.css";
import Cross from "./Cross";
import Circle from "./Circle";


export default function BoardBox(props){

        return(
            <div onClick={() => {
                props.markBox(props.row + 3*props.col, 1);
                console.log(props.boxes)
                }} className="BoardBox">
            {props.marked === true ? (props.markedPlayer === 1 ? <Cross/> : (props.markedPlayer === 2 ?  <Circle/> : "")): ""}

            </div>
        );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente encontré el error. En markbox defino una variable `boxes` y la igualo al estado `boardBoxes` y luego de modificar un valor actualizo el estado `setBoardBoxes(boxes)`. Y el problema está en que React reconoce `boxes` como el mismo array pero con un valor cambiado, entonces no actualiza el componente. Para solucionarlo solo cambio la linea por `setBoardBoxes([...boxes]);`. Utilizando el spread operator creo un nuevo array que incluye los valores en `boxes` y React actualiza el componente.